# Controlling the order of execution of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to test a multithreader scenario where the threads execute in a specic order so I can be confident I have correct behaviour for this scenario.

Let's say:
ThreadA has methods `1()` and `2()`.  ThreadB has methods `3()` and `4()`.

I want the order of execution to be:

```
ThreadA.1() 
ThreadB.3() 
ThreadA.2()
ThreadB.4()
```

I could do this by passing in a command to ThreadA and ThreadB to tell them what method to execute and the by join-ing on each thread before restarting the next thread.

I was just wondering if there was a more elegant to do this.

Note, this is test code, I wish to test a certain scenario.

Many thanks.

Comment: If you want sequential execution, then why use multiple threads?

Comment: "ClassB has methods 3() and 4()." then "classB.2()". But classB doesn't have a method 2()...

Comment: doesn't this defeat the point of threading in the first place?

Comment: It's test code. I want to test a certain scenario.

Comment: See this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461543/run-java-threads-sequentially

Answer (score 1):

Have each thread wait on producer-consumer queues. Submit an object containing both Class instances and a state-variable to queue 1.  In thread 1, do classA.1() and submit the object to queue 2.  In thread 2, do classB.2() and submit the object to queue 1 .....

Don't use join, synchronize etc. with any thread stuff that is above trivial - you will just get in a mess of deadlocks, poor performance and nightmare debugging.

Pass objects on P-C queues - deadlock, while not impossible, is very difficult :)

If you can arrange for any stuff, anywhere to be thread-agnostic, you should do so.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question was asked badly (you said classA had methods 1() and 2(), but... then your example didn't follow that at all.

However, if you want to add some semblance of order between threads without explicitly join()ing or run()ing them, you can give them access to each other (using a singleton class, for example, that would act as an easily-accessible intermediary), and, once you've gotten to a point where you want the one thread to wait for the other thread to perform a certain task, you can use a wait statement in a synchronized block within a while loop as follows:

```
while (!Singleton.finished()) {
    synchronized (this) {
        wait();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do u want 2 threads if you have only order of execution? Just execute them one after the other.

anyway, you can use the following code:

```
void synchronized executor(){
    Thread threadA = new Thread( new Runnable(){
       @Override
       void run(){
            classA.1();//or the equivalent object
            Thread.notify();
       }
    }
    threadA.run();
    threadA.wait();
    Thread threadB = new Thread( new Runnable(){
       @Override
       void run(){
            classB.3();//or the equivalent object
            Thread.notify();
       }
    }
    threadB.run();
    threadB.wait();
    Thread threadA = new Thread( new Runnable(){
       @Override
       void run(){
            classA.2();//or the equivalent object
            Thread.notify();
       }
    }
    threadA.run();
    threadA.wait();
    Thread threadB = new Thread( new Runnable(){
       @Override
       void run(){
            classB.4();//or the equivalent object
            Thread.notify();
       }
    }
    threadB.run();
}
```

as you can see there is no elegant way to do this.

Comment: I am updated question to make things clearer. Thanks for you comments.