# How to end threads in a specific order using join() /wait() /notify combination?

Tags: java, multithreading

Lets say I have 3 threads which implement a Runnable interface, and I've started them using below statements.

```
t1.start();
t2.start(); 
t3.start();
```

Is there any way using `join()`, `wait()`, `notify()` combination to make threads end in this order t3 , t2, t1 ?

Comment: Unclear. Threads usually terminate, when their `run` methods terminate. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Given that threads are started at same time, I need a working code in such a way that threads end in mentioned order using join/wait/notify.

Comment: This is what you already told us. And I asked you: What problem are you trying to solve? Threads run asynchronously. So why think about an ordering, especially an order about ending those threads? Your question looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Do they run infinite loop each ? If not what causes the treads to terminate ?

Comment: Lets say there are 3 threads, and each one populates different results...required by other threads. So, other threads have to wait until results are available even though they start at same time. For eg: t3 produces some result which t2 will require. Since both have started at same time and t3 is not yet complete, t2 will have to wait until t3 is done.

Comment: You can do this control flow a number of ways. Do you want a producer consumer model? Or you could use a Semaphore or countdown latch? Why do you have 3 threads? Could you need 5 threads? What sort of control do you need, as in how would t1 know when it is finished and t3 etc.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/12989397/3992939

Comment: so what you want to do is not to terminate in a specific order, but to start in a specific order

Comment: so what you need is to run threads in a sequential way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461543/run-java-threads-sequentially

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, the threads will terminate depending on what happens inside of their `run()` method implementations. If you're simply given a currently-running thread without any access to the code it's executing, there is no way to force it to terminate (aside from calling `stop()` or `destroy()`, which are both deprecated and should not be used).

If you can write the code that these threads are running, however, it'd be really simple:

```
Thread t3 = new Thread(() -> { 
    System.out.println("Thread 3 terminating..."); 
});

Thread t2 = new Thread(() -> {
    try { t3.join(); } catch(InterruptedException e) {}; 
    System.out.println("Thread 2 terminating..."); 
});

Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
    try { t2.join(); } catch(InterruptedException e) {}; 
    System.out.println("Thread 1 terminating..."); 
});

t1.start();
t2.start(); 
t3.start();
```

Comment: but be sure to put joins at the end of your run method, otherwise you just will block a thread till the others finishes, here you are not asking threads to finish, but you ask them not to finish before others..

Comment: This works. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you might want a producer consumer model.

```
BlockingQueue<Callable<Boolean>> queue1 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

Thread t1 = new Thread(()->{
   //do work.
   queue1.add(()-> someTask() );
   //do more work.
   queue1.add(()-> someTaskThatReturnsFalse() );
}).start();

Thread t2 = new Thread(()->{
     boolean shouldBeRunning = true;
     while(shouldBeRunning){

        Callable<Boolean> r = queue1.poll();
        shouldBeRunning = r.call();
     }
}).start();
```

You can have as many queues as you like. There are other ways too using locks and barriers. This could be done using join/wait/notify but you would essentially be re-creating the `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer would be non-useful. From ops description "...each one populates different results" Which sounds exactly like a producer. "other threads have to wait until results are available " which sounds like a consumer.